# Javascript: How to get value of textbox in form, then append them to a predefined string AND redirect browser to the value of the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textbox

I would like need help with a simple code. It needs to do the following:

1. Ask the user to input a value in a textbox (e.g. '12345').
2. Get the value entered and append them to a default URL string (e.g. 'http://mywebsite.com/track/').
3. Redirect the browser URL to the new value (e.g. http://mywebsite.com/track/12345').

I was thinking about parsing the value via a GET/POST command, but I don't want the question mark that will get added when you submit it, so Javascript would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="urlInput" value="12345"><br>

<p>Click "GO" to be redirected to the URL.</p>

<button onclick="redirect()">GO</button>

<script>
function redirect() {
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/track/" + document.getElementById('urlInput').value;
window.location=url;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks heaps!!!! You just saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this:

```
var new_url = prompt();
window.location.replace(new_url);
```

You get input from user with `promt()` and you save it in `variable` named `new_url`. After that you use `replace()` method for redirecting. You change the location of `window object`